# Change text of CreateUser button in CreateUserWizard control

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

I've seen a lot of customization questions, but I still haven't seen how to just change the text of the CreateUser button. It seems that the button it automatically showing despite already switching it to a custom template.

Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I had looked for a simple line to change it the other day when I was in a hurry (in front of the customer) and didn't find it. I figured it wasn't there, but it was.

```
CreateUserButtonText="whatever you want"
```

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.createuserbuttontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): You can simply use `CreateUserButtonText` property:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard CreateUserButtonText="String" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the smart tag select Convert To CustomNavigation Template and then go to the markup. You can change whatever you want.

It works with me